# Android: Fast Forward or Pause TTS

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I understand how to do basic tts in android. I understand you can't really pause or fast forward the speech. However, it is possible to skip to the next or previous sentence in the string. How do you do this. Also how do work with the 5000 char limit.
Thanks in advance. You'll be doing a favor for a lot of people.